# Automatically fetch data from API within hybrid app

Tags: cordova, vue.js, cordova-plugins, nuxt.js

I’m setting up an hybrid app using Cordova. I need to match a GET request to a server to fetch some data that’s in JSON format, this data from the server automatically updates with new data every now and then, several times a day at a non-consistent time.

My goal is to ping a notification on the phone, via a Cordova plugin whenever the data on the server changes, I need to somehow automatically listen and dynamically fetch the new data whenever it changes, how would one recommend I do this and potentially with what Cordova plugin? I need to use as little mobile data as possible, but on wi-fi it shouldn’t be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the description of what you are trying to accomplish, you should consider push to device instead of doing GETs

Comment: Do you have an example? I need my GET requests to work even with the app closed, could you recommend a plugin for this?

Comment: I'm using Vue Axios currently set on a setInterval, not sure if there's a better solution

Comment: Yes, just check out google firebase plugin and do push to your app. It will get the app started if the user taps the notification.

Comment: I'm not using Firebase in my project, and I don't need it. I'm not sure how adding this is going to achieve what I need? my GET request using Vue Axios isn't from Firebase, it's from another URL